# How can I use FFMpeg with PHP in a Vagrant environment?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, vagrant

I've got this working on a DigitalOcean server, but I can't seem to get it working locally.

My Vagrant box is [ubuntu/trusty64](https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64). When I ssh into the machine to check out the permissions of the `ffmpeg` binary, it's `664`. I tried running `chmod 755 ffmpeg` (w/ and w/o `sudo`), but it has no effect and outputs no response. I'm the owner, so `chown` wouldn't make any difference (but also doesn't work, w/ or w/o `sudo`). Outside of the Vagrant machine, the file permissions are `755` and owned by me, though that doesn't seem to matter.

The binaries are static builds from a [site linked to](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) on the [official FFMpeg site's download page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

Running `cat /etc/*-release` on both the remote DO server and the Vagrant machine returns the same result:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

When attempting to execute the binary through PHP on the Vagrant machine (with `exec()`), I get a `126` exit code.

What else should I try to get this working?